# How to get sync token for Asana events api

Tags: asana

I am looking at the events API here

> https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/events

I see that requests need a sync token which, I assume, is analogous to the SHA1 changeset hash of git. However, I didnt see how to ask for the first sync token.  Also get back a sync token so that I know at that point what state the   Also, Is the events API stable enough to use?  I noticed it said that **Note: The complete list of available events is still in flux.**

thx, alan

Answer (score 2):

The events API is not only unstable, it's currently disabled for stability reasons. Once it's back, the simple answer is that the first request you make errors, but also sends back a sync token you can use for the next request. Each response contains the sync token for the next request. And if it ever becomes invalid (expires, for example) you'll get another error and a new sync token. The error basically signals that you need to re-fetch the full state if you're trying to do something sync-ish. If you're only interested in reacting to events, you can skip that part, but you might have missed some in the meantime.

The documentation will be more fleshed out when it's ready for public consumption, and those answers should be more readily apparent.

Comment: Do you work for asana? Erroring really isn't an acceptable way to respond to an expected call.

Comment: Yes, I do work for asana! We went back and forth on this one a bit. In the end we decided that a) we wanted to keep the behavior consistent to make it easier to handle (so whether you came in with no sync token or with an expired sync token), and b) we wanted to throw an error to help make it obvious that this was a special case needing special handling. I get that it feels weird to get an error on this case, but the consistency win seemed big enough to us that it was worth it. Better to get the surprise up-front than later on when your data is inconsistent ;-)

Comment: The events api seems fine at the moment but you still need to make a first request to get a sync key as @agnoster mentioned in his reply. This creates trouble about getting the last events since last synchronisation. I hope Asana adds a new method to generate our own sync key soon.

Comment: @emreoktem - Getting the last events since last synchronization, you just use the last sync token you got from Asana. That's what it's actually designed for. If you create your own, we wouldn't know what to keep track of for you - so it's necessary to have sync tokens generated by Asana. It will never be possible to generate your own sync tokens.

Comment: @agnoster hi, thanks for the response. I am working on an application which will consume events via your API and when the consumer has opened the app, I can't get latest events i.e. of last 1 day (duration is just an example). It would be great if it was possible to create a sync key for a specific duration or using only /events method without providing a sync key to get predefined number of events of a project.

Comment: @emreoktem because we actually track events once we know someone is subscribing to them, we can't make retroactive subscriptions. if we fundamentally change the architecture that *could* change, but based on the somewhat complex access control rules this is unlikely to be feasible

Comment: @emreoktem what you *can* do is determine which tasks in a project changed since a specific timestamp using modified_since, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Generate first sync token - provide the resource(project) id

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer authtoken" \
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/events?resource=145619319717806&sync=1
```

In response - you will get first token to be used for event subscription:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Sync token invalid or too old. If you are
>   attemping to keep resources in sync, you must fetch the full dataset
>   for this query now and use the new sync token for the next
>   sync."}],"sync":"token"}

Use the sync token provided from previous request, like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer authtoken" \
"https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/events?resource=145619319717806&sync=<sync-token>"
```

In response, you will get events and next sync token. Use this sync token for further events.

Reference: [Asana Events API](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/events)